# Laptop with Wi-Fi 6 and only USB-C

Tags: laptop

Seems it's hard to find laptops with only USB-C and no USB-A. It's also hard to find laptops with Wi-Fi 6. The laptop would charge using the USB-C port only.

Do you know any with a combination of these? Like an updated Zenbook 3.

Comment: Certification for WiFi 6 just became available on Sept 16, 2019. Give OEMs a few more months and you will find many more WiFi 6 devices. Also USB-A is still in demand; Most people still need to use USB-A peripherals like mice, USB drives, and printers. Even though a C to A adapter would work for those people, it's annoying to need one for *every* device you want to plug in.

Comment: @Romen I have a USB-C hub on my desk 

Comment: So is that the reason you *do not* want USB-A ports? What is the downside you see in having a USB-A port?

Comment: @Romen the thickness of the laptop, they take too much space. I want to get rid of all my USB-A and B cables.

Comment: That's a fair reason to forgo USB-A, have you considered Windows tablet PCs? You want something too thin for USB-A, but if it was that thin it would be also too thin to fit a keyboard & the guts for a laptop. There are some laptops that push the limits on reducing thickness, but they often use the same components as tablet PCs.

Comment: This seems like a bit of an [X Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - instead of saying _no USB A_ state your maximum desired thickness